# What would an table-top RPGer want/need of a Q&A community?

Tags: discussion

This is a response to [“How is the site going” entry in area51. Comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/how-is-the-site-going-entry-in-area51-comments)

We need to market the community more, or more effectively. Part of that is asking ourselves what we offer, and what potential users need.

What do potential users, RPGers, need - both in general, and of us?

And which of those needs to we fulfill? What are circumstances when you'd be able to snap your fingers at someone and go "Oh man! You so need to join rpg.stackexchange.com!"

Once we can answer this, I think it could be easier to market the site.

Comment: "Right now our current rules are getting in the way of potential users' needs and this is slowing us down." Examples please.

Comment: @C. Ross - This question is probably moot: @Pat Ludwig has [rebuttled my opinion very well](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/556/how-is-the-site-going-entry-in-area51-comments/581#581). I will probably delete it.

Comment: @C. Ross - I rephrased; I still think this is a relevant question.

Comment: I think it's a legit question too.  Just disagreed with some of the assertions.

Answer (score 5):

A) *Get your RPG rules questions answered, fast.*

That's the number one reason why people should come to this site. Plain and simple. There are lots of other ways that users can find value, but this is the one where the Stack Exchange Q&A site format really shines. A few others that come to mind:

B) *Get help making your chararacter.* Find out how to calculate the point cost for your super-powers. Get a rules clarification. Hunt down that obscure splat book ability.

C) *Get GM advice.* Get help balancing your encounters. Find obscure source material for your campaign. Learn how to be a good referee. Get better at making the game fun.

D) *Connect with other gamers.* Check out the chatroom, see what new game's on the table. Reminisce about old times. Play with the dice bot.

I think it's inevitable that this site work best as a GM resource. An RPG player's primary Q&A resource is "Ask the GM" (hey, that could be a good tagline). That may be only a narrow subset of RPG gamers, but for those people, it's a gold mine. =)

Comment: Added an entry to the tagline question after writing this: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/553/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline/585#585

Answer (score -2):

Table top RPGers want flexibility; that's why we play table top and not computer games. We like rules, but we like bending them and tossing them out the window sometimes for the sake of drama, adventure or even just plain fun.

Comment: Maybe this can't apply to the Q&A site, but it's something _very_ relevant which defines most table top RPGers and deserves at least mention here.

Comment: At the same time, when someone asks for clarification on a particular rule, I'd rather not see someone jump in with, "Whatever the rule is, the GM should allow it" or some variation.

Comment: But you want flexibility within the context of providing better game play. You wouldn't want a player who **defines "flexibility" as throwing everyone's game pieces around the room**. Neither would you want a Q&A site with *flexibility* in any old way you define it, as your post suggests.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino - Agreed. Again, I don't think this is something the _site_ needs, but it's something which defines RPGers enough to merit note.